# Is it possible to create a custom Core Data Persistent Storage Coordinator?

Tags: ios, database, macos, core-data

I'm curious if it is possible to create a custom Persistent Storage Coordinator so that you could use Core Data to interact with different storage systems, i.e. Windows Azure or S3. Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find any information about custom Persistent Storage Coordinators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at the new support for NSIncrementalStore and NSIncrementalStoreNode in iOS5 (see [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3)). These allow you to implement support for non-atomic persistent stores such as web services as a back-end for Core Data.